# Chart.js not showing in Android 8.0/Android O

Tags: android, chart.js

I have an android app which using Chart.js for showing some graph. Recently, I tried to check whether the chart.js is it able to work in the latest preview of Android 8 / Android O. However, the graph is not able to show on the app with the phone running Android 8 / Android O. When I roll back the phone to Android 7, the graph is able to show. I am using the latest Chart.js which is v2.6.

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: is there and error ? with just your description, it's impossible to do anything

Comment: android 8 is in preview maybe you need to add it as an issues at the lib website

Comment: This has nothing to do with ChartJS. Maybe your code is not being complied in the latest version of Android.

Comment: is Android 8 released?

Comment: Android 8 not yet released, but it is in preview state. https://developer.android.com/preview/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I resolved temporarily with [issue #4570 Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4570) but I waiting that help me solve the problem completely, making Chart.js work normally.

Workaround Solution - displays the chart but actions will be lost (mouse click, hover over etc):

1- Wrap your canvas within a Div (add any styles to the div you may need)

```
<div><canvas height="400" id="myChart" width="400"></canvas></div>
```

2- Suggest removing any 'animation' (although you could alter the code below in item 3/ to use the endAnimation event to track when to carry out the temp fix) - Add into your options:

```
options: { animation:{duration:0}, ..... }
```

3- Add the following code - have made this simple, but could be improved re end of animation if required:

(jQuery)

```
$('#myChart').parent().html('<img style="max-height:100%;height:auto;width:100%;max-width:100%;margin:auto;display:inline;" src="' + chart.toBase64Image() + '" />');
```

(javascript)

```
document.getElementById('myChart').parentElement.innerHTML = '<img style="max-height:100%;height:auto;width:100%;max-width:100%;margin:auto;display:inline;" src="' + chart.toBase64Image() + '" />';
```

Follow [issue #5184 Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5184) on Github